Analyzing an experiment which consists of many "small" experiments
Consider the following setting: I am trying to choose between two bakers for my new bakery, Baker A and Baker B. The way that I am evaluating them is on a set of different cakes on the menu: Cake 1, Cake 2, ..., Cake N. I asked each baker to bake a cake of each type, so we have Cake 1A, Cake 1B, etc.
Now I run the following experiment. Customers walk into my store and suppose they are interested in one type of cake. I then randomly give either the A or B variant and ask them if they like it or not. At the end of the day, for each cake variant, I'll have a fraction of the form # liked / total. I might have a dataset containing fractions that looks something like this:



Cake
Baker A
Baker B




1
3/10
6/11


2
20/33
25/35


3
4/5
5/5


4
100/250
140/245


5
2/10
2/9


6
250/300
290/300



Specific questions:

Is there a name for this kind of experiment? It seems to me that actually there is a separate experiment for each cake.
How would you analyze this experiment? I would like to say something like "Baker B improves the like-rate of Baker A by X%". Naively, I could get the percent increase for each row of the table, and then average over all rows. Or I could take the difference of each row, and then average over all rows. What would I be missing if I did that?
In reality, there might be many many possible cakes, i.e., N is large. I am therefore taking a sample of possible cakes, and for each cake, running an experiment.


What would you be missing? You would be missing out on using the information that a statistical model can bring. Your naive approach is OK if this was really about cakes and bakers, but it doesn't distinguish between 4/5 and 4000/5000 and the precision of estimate that you get from those two results is very very different. It doesn't for example, allow you to decide how many cakes need to be sold before a decision regarding the bakers might be reliable.

Are these different types of cakes or just multiple instances of the same cake (say, made on different days)?

@dimitriy These are different types of cakes, edited the question for clarity. In other words, we want to find the baker that does well on the entire menu (in other words, across some population distribution of cakes).

@MichaelLew Thank you! Handling the precision of the estimate is my main concern as well. What are my options in terms of modeling?
(1) The first one that I had in mind was to do it at the customer level and the model would predict, for a single customer, whether they like a particular cake or not (0 or 1). This would essentially create a table with one row per customer.
(2) Is there an alternative to the customer-level model that allows me to use the table format above?

@MichaelLew
A follow-up is that in my real problem, the number of "cakes" is gigantic, let's say 1 million. In my understanding, such experiments might typically be analyzed by adding a dummy variable for each cake, but that seems unwieldy here when the number of cakes is so large. Is the alternative to add cake covariates to the model?

I have no idea. Perhaps you should write about your actual setting instead of the cakes...

Why not compute, for each cake, the difference between bake A and baker B using risk difference, risk ratio, or odds ratio and then use standard meta-analysis methods? You may have to look around for software which will handle millions of cakes.

This is a standard A/B test if you view cakes as the sample from a population of products (rather than customers), with a varying number of taste tests (aka trials) for each cake.
Your proposed approach ignores the precision difference from the varying number of trials, as @MichaelLew already pointed out.
How would you analyze this experiment? Try fitting a panel Poisson model with random effects for each cake type and a dummy for baker B (or A), with the number of trials as the exposure variable. This is appropriate for when you have a sample of cakes drawn from a population and want to conduct inference on that population on the exposure to the two bakers. The cake random effects are assumed to be uncorrelated with the baker dummy, which is the case here since you are randomizing customers. I think this should be easily computable with millions of cakes in the test thanks to a computational trick that precludes estimating those parameters.
The Poisson model for the expected number of likes for cake $c$ is
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}[L_{c} \mid baker, trials] &= \exp \left( \alpha + \beta_B + 1 \cdot \ln(trials) + \nu_c \right) \\
&=\underbrace{\exp \left( \nu_c \right)}_{\text{cake factor}} \cdot \underbrace{\exp \left( \alpha + \beta_B \right)}_{\text{baker effect}} \cdot \underbrace{trials}_{\text{trials factor}}
\end{aligned}
such that $\exp(\nu_c)$ comes from a gamma distribution with mean one and a variance estimated from the data. The $\nu$s are nuisance parameters and are integrated out using a computational trick (no 1e6 dummies needed). The intuition for $1
\cdot \ln(trials)$ is explained here. It is essentially a scaling factor so that more trials lead to more likes.
To compare what happens to likes with Baker B versus A, you can calculate the ratio of the corresponding expected values:
$$ \begin{aligned} 
\frac{\mathbb{E}[L_{c} \mid baker=B, trials]}{\mathbb{E}[L_{c} \mid baker=A, trials]} & = \frac{ \exp \left(\alpha + \beta_B + 1 \cdot \ln(trials) + \nu_c \right)}{ \exp \left(\alpha + 1 \cdot \ln(trials) + \nu_c\right)} \\ & = \exp \left(\beta_B \right) \end{aligned}$$
This is called an incidence-rate ratio (IRR).
This approach requires changing the data structure to have two rows for each cake type corresponding to each baker. Here's an example using Stata on the data you have provided:
. clear

. input int cake str1 baker int(likes trials)

         cake      baker     likes    trials
  1. 1       "A"             3               10
  2. 1   "B"         6               11
  3. 2       "A"             20              33
  4. 2   "B"         25              35
  5. 3       "A"             4               5
  6. 3   "B"         5               5
  7. 4       "A"             100             250
  8. 4   "B"         140             245
  9. 5       "A"             2               10
 10. 5   "B"         2               9
 11. 6       "A"             250             300
 12. 6   "B"         290             300
 13. end

. strrec baker ("A" = 0 "A") ("B" = 1 "B"), replace
baker
(6 real changes made)
(6 real changes made)

. xtset cake baker

Panel variable: cake (strongly balanced)
 Time variable: baker, 0 to 1
         Delta: 1 unit

. list, noobs sepby(cake)

  +-------------------------------+
  | cake   baker   likes   trials |
  |-------------------------------|
  |    1       A       3       10 |
  |    1       B       6       11 |
  |-------------------------------|
  |    2       A      20       33 |
  |    2       B      25       35 |
  |-------------------------------|
  |    3       A       4        5 |
  |    3       B       5        5 |
  |-------------------------------|
  |    4       A     100      250 |
  |    4       B     140      245 |
  |-------------------------------|
  |    5       A       2       10 |
  |    5       B       2        9 |
  |-------------------------------|
  |    6       A     250      300 |
  |    6       B     290      300 |
  +-------------------------------+

. xtpoisson likes i.baker, exposure(trials) ir nolog vce(cluster cake) re

Random-effects Poisson regression                    Number of obs    =     12
Group variable: cake                                 Number of groups =      6

Random effects u_i ~ Gamma                           Obs per group:
                                                                  min =      2
                                                                  avg =    2.0
                                                                  max =      2

                                                     Wald chi2(1)     =  19.13
Log pseudolikelihood = -38.221375                    Prob > chi2      = 0.0000

                                   (Std. err. adjusted for 6 clusters in cake)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
       likes |        IRR   std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       baker |
          B  |    1.23783   .0720903     3.66   0.000     1.104302    1.387505
       _cons |   .5428042   .1001355    -3.31   0.001     .3781073      .77924
  ln(trials) |          1  (exposure)
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
    /lnalpha |  -2.196434   1.271774                     -4.689066    .2961978
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       alpha |    .111199     .14142                      .0091953    1.344736
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Note: Estimates are transformed only in the first equation to incidence-rate ratios.
Note: _cons estimates baseline incidence rate (conditional on zero random effects).
LR test of alpha=0: chibar2(01) = 62.40                Prob >= chibar2 = 0.000

The multiplicative effect of Baker B is estimated as 1.23783. Here Stata reports the exponentiated coefficient on the Baker B dummy. It can be interpreted as saying that using Baker B will give you 1.24X more likes than using Baker A. Equivalently, that is 24% more likes with a standard error of 7.2%. The 95% confidence interval is $[10\%, 39\%]$, which rules out no effect (or a multiplicative effect of one).
You could also try a customer-level, panel logit with cake random effects, though that requires blowing up your data so each row is a customer like or dislike. Here's what I get in Stata:
. rename likes likes1

. gen likes0 = trials - likes1 // dislikes

. drop trials

. reshape long likes, i(cake baker) j(rating)
(j = 0 1)

Data                               Wide   ->   Long
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Number of observations               12   ->   24          
Number of variables                   4   ->   4           
j variable (2 values)                     ->   rating
xij variables:
                          likes0 likes1   ->   likes
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

. rename likes noobs

. expand noobs
(1 zero count ignored; observation not deleted)
(1,190 observations created)

. drop noobs

. sort cake baker rating

. xtset cake

Panel variable: cake (unbalanced)

. xtlogit rating i.baker, re nolog vce(cluster cake)

Calculating robust standard errors ...

Random-effects logistic regression                   Number of obs    =  1,214
Group variable: cake                                 Number of groups =      6

Random effects u_i ~ Gaussian                        Obs per group:
                                                                  min =     11
                                                                  avg =  202.3
                                                                  max =    600

Integration method: mvaghermite                      Integration pts. =     12

                                                     Wald chi2(1)     =  13.58
Log pseudolikelihood = -602.48211                    Prob > chi2      = 0.0002

                                   (Std. err. adjusted for 6 clusters in cake)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
      rating | Coefficient  std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       baker |
          B  |   .8966102   .2432678     3.69   0.000     .4198141    1.373406
       _cons |   .0331591   .4760794     0.07   0.944    -.8999394    .9662577
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
    /lnsig2u |   .2735993   .5379316                     -.7807272    1.327926
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     sigma_u |   1.146598   .3083958                      .6768107    1.942475
         rho |   .2855189   .1097369                      .1222198     .534216
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. margins, eydx(baker) predict(pr)

Conditional marginal effects                             Number of obs = 1,214
Model VCE: Robust

Expression: Pr(rating=1), predict(pr)
ey/dx wrt:  1.baker

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      ey/dx   std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       baker |
          B  |   .2896812   .0489742     5.91   0.000     .1936935    .3856689
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Note: ey/dx for factor levels is the discrete change from the base level.

The RE panel logit estimate is +29% increase in the probability of getting a like when using Baker B, with a 95%CI of $[19\%, 39\%]$. That's not widely different from the Poisson effect, which is reassuring. This is probably a good robustness check to do and also allows you to add customer effects/covariates to the model.

Thank you for the fantastic and helpful answer. This is the path I will go down!

A quick follow-up question: what's the benefit of doing a poisson regression vs a binomial regression?

@gaussiandynamics I am unaware of any panel version of binomial regression, so you would need to include cake fixed effects (a series of binary variables that are one if the cake is Z, zero otherwise). This can be computationally difficult since you would have num(cakes)-1 additional parameters in the model. The advantage of the Poisson is that it treats those as nuisance parameters, and they drop out of the conditional likelihood. This makes life much easier.

That makes a lot of sense, thanks! I ended up trying glmer with cake random effects using both Poisson and binomial versions and they showed similar results.

dimitry (+1 to his answer) has the right idea here.  Treat the cakes as nuisance variables and use a Poisson model to estimate the risk ratio between bakers A and B.
In R, you can handle a million experiments quite easily using fixest.  Now, I'm not an economist (perhaps the primary user of such fixed effects models), but I believe you can do something like I've done below.
I've simulated 1 million experiments for 2 groups.  Each group has an experiment specific effect (biostatisticians would call this a random effect, economists an idiosyncratic effect).  The base group's probability of success on the logit scale is -2 while the odds ratio for the other group is 1.  This means that the probability of success in the B=1 group is roughly 2.25 times larger than that in the B=0 group.  Let's run the regression for an -- eyewatering -- 2 million total observations.
library(fixest)
sim_data <- function(n){
  set.seed(0)  
  N <- rpois(2*n, 100)
  B <- rep(0:1, each=n)
  experiment <- rep(1:n, 2)
  z <- rnorm(n, 0, 0.2)
  
  p <- boot::inv.logit(-2 + B + z[experiment])
  
  y <- rbinom(2*n, N, p)
  
  
  data.frame(y, N, p, z, B, experiment)
  
}

d <- sim_data(1000000)

fit <- fepois(
  y ~ B|experiment, 
  offset = log(d$N),
  data=d,
  vcov = ~experiment
)


fit
#> Poisson estimation, Dep. Var.: y
#> Observations: 2,000,000
#> Offset: log(d$N)
#> Fixed-effects: experiment: 1,000,000
#> Standard-errors: Clustered (experiment) 
#>   Estimate Std. Error z value  Pr(>|z|)    
#> B 0.806887   0.000317 2543.62 < 2.2e-16 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> Log-Likelihood: -5,126,941.2   Adj. Pseudo R2: 0.328246
#>            BIC: 24,762,554.6     Squared Cor.: 0.918825

Created on 2024-06-11 with reprex v2.1.0
fixest handles it no probelm.  I've also clustered the standard error by the experiment (since we've sampled experiments and not individuals).  Note the coefficient for the B variable is 0.8.  Once exponentiated, this means that the risk in the B=1 group is exp(0.8) ~ 2.25 times larger than that of the B=0 group.  Right where it should be.

Thank you Demetri! I suspect I will need to use fixest to handle my application with a huge number of experiments.

(I cannot upvote you since I'm a new user, but your answer was very helpful)
